# How can i pass a string value, that has been created in an if statement, through a bundle inside another if statement?

Tags: android, string, if-statement, bundle

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Declare Variables to be used
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    final CheckBox checkbox01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);


    //All if statements for builds
    final Button findbuilds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_FindBuildsTab1);{
        findbuilds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if ((v==findbuilds)&&(checkbox01.getText()==("Ahri-AP"))&&((checkbox01).isChecked())){
                     final String charactername = "Ahri-AP";
                 }
                 if ((checkbox01).isChecked(){
                   //All Bundles are placed here
                     bundle.putString("CharacterName Value Key", charactername);

                   //Start Tabhost Activity and pass bundle(s)
                     Intent nextActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                     nextActivity.putExtras(bundle);
                     startActivity(nextActivity); TabHostActivity.class);
                 }
```

Basically, what i am trying to do is create the string for the character's name in the first if-statement, and then bundle it in another if-statement.  The reason i need to bundle the string(s) in a different if-statement is to avoid reaching the bytes limit of a method.  I have a total of 64 different Strings that need to be bundled for each if-statement, and i have a total of 126 if-statements that need to happen.  The problem is of course that the String variable is never found or resolved with the bundle in the 2nd if-statement.  Is there a way to do this?  Or maybe a more efficient way?  Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pull the definition of your variable outside of the if statement. eg:

```
final String charactername 
if() {
    charactername = ...
}
if() {
    bundle stuff with charactername 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what i needed.  I started with the variable outside the if-statement, but was changing the value incorrectly, using replaceAll().  Thank you so much!!